# Cannot POST to server even with CORS

Tags: javascript, post, xmlhttprequest, cors

I am trying to send a POST to a given server. I am using an XMLHttpRequest and I keep getting 
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://example.org. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access. I understand the concept of CORS and I have added

```
http_connection.withCredentials = true;
http_connection.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
http_connection.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
```

though they might not all be necessary. I am still getting the error. Is there something else with XMLHttpRequests I can try? More over how can I see if the given server just simply cannot be POSTed to?

Comment: That's not how CORS work, the headers are set on the response from the server.

Comment: @Musa The what is the purpose of the Origin, Access-Control-Request-Method, and Access-Control-Request-Method headers?

Comment: `Access-Control-Request-Method` allows you to restrict or allow requests by http verb e.g. `POST`, `GET`, `DELETE`, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't get it. Those headers have to be sent **by the server**, not by you. It is the server who's got to allow you access via AJAX.

If CORS could be enabled by the client code, it wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: Then my two request Headers are pointless, so then other than the credential switch what can I do?

Comment: If you don't have access to the web server, or can get the server administrator to enable the CORS headers, the only solution would be to create a proxy in your own server. You would make requests to your server, your server would ask the remote server and then would return the responses to you.

Answer (score 0):

The fix would be to add the headers to the response sent by the server, but then, you **should** be careful with that.

In most scenarios, this occurs when you're developing locally but the API is on another machine. There is a *very ugly* way to do it in Chrome.

On a Mac, you need to do:

```
open -a Google\ Chrome --args --disable-web-security
```

in a terminal. I believe there are very similar workarounds for other OS's as well.

But ofcourse, this is not a good way to go about it. I'd tweak the development servers to send me the headers which allow access from the development domain.

Comment: It works on Windows as well (`chrome --disable-web-security`). I always open Chrome that way in my development machine. Chrome will tell you the option is not allowed, but it does work. Of course, this is only a solution for development. Normal users won't have this enabled.

Answer (score 0):

`--disable-web-security` works but makes your browser's security vulnerable, you might get any viruses or malwares from the internet.